# GET function console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**The logic:**

my_function looks through file.txt, if it finds the word "Hello", returns true. If not, false.

**The problem:**

Uncaught type error: contents.includes is not a function

**Limitations:**

Can only use plain javascript

```
function my_function() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(contents) {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
//contents variable now contains the contents of the textfile as string

//check if text file contains the word Hello
var hasString = contents.includes("Hello");

//outputs true if contained, else false
console.log(hasString);

}
};
xhttp.open("GET",  "http://www.example.com/file.txt", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: @Tushar If I use includes() with jquery GET function works.

Comment: Try `var hasString = contents.indexOf("Hello") > -1;` Also, check if `includes` is supported in your browser.

Comment: You need to check if the "contents" is not empty/undefined 

add this:

    var hasString;
    if (contents !== undefined && contents !== "") {
          hasString = contents.includes("Hello");
    }

Make sure the result coming back is not empty. Checking the status is not enough in this context.

Comment: @Malasorte Let me know if that works. Execute `'abc'.includes('a')` in browser and see if you're getting error or `true`.

Comment: @Tushar I get true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this.responseText instead of that parameter contents
this.responseText is the response of your ajax

```
function my_function() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //contents variable now contains the contents of the textfile as string

            //check if text file contains the word Hello
            var hasString = this.responseText.includes("Hello");

            //outputs true if contained, else false
            console.log(hasString);

        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET",  "http://www.example.com/file.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!